# Spotlight UI unable to find Core Data external record files inside Sandbox

Tags: cocoa, core-data, spotlight, appstore-sandbox, spotlight-plugin

I've followed the instructions to integrate spotlight into a non-document based Core Data application using [Record-Level Indexing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/SpotlightCoreData/Articles/recordLevel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008065-CH101-SW2). The spotlight importer imports the files correctly and those records can be found using `mdfind "some string"`.

The problem is the spotlight user interface – the magnifying glass in the top right – doesn't show these records when running inside the sandbox.

The external record files are created in `~/Library/Containers/[my app]/Data/Library/Caches/Metadata/CoreData/[my app]`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing the results of `mdimport -d2 [external record file]` showed this extra property:

```
kMDItemSupportFileType =     (
    MDSystemFile
);
```

Adjusting the spotlight importer to remove this key seems to fix it. The results are now shown in the spotlight UI. I'm guessing it hides system files from the results.

```
[spotlightData removeObjectForKey:@"kMDItemSupportFileType"];
```

Comment: is there anyway you share some basic code here. I just cant seem to get it from the "Record level indexing" page of apple docs.